# How to pass variable from one function to other in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I connected Mysql & Oracle databases through php.
Now in one function say dbInsert(), I have store data inserted in mysql database in one variable. Now I close connection with Mysql.
Then I open connectio for Oracle database & trying to get that variable so that I can insert those value in Oracle.
But problem I am not getting those Mysql values in Oracle connection in that variable...
If I use it w/o function then file run fine but in class-function structure , it's not working... 
I have tried using global variable but effort in vain...
plz help...

I am posting only those functions as code is too large...
I have declared $str as global variable...& passing that in Oracle's oradbInsert().

```
function dbFetch(){
            $a = mysql_insert_id();    
                $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample where order_primary = $a");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){$str = "'".$row["po_number"]."',"."'".$row[created_at]."',"."'".$row["ustomer_firstname"]."',"."'".$row["customer_lastname"]."',"."'".$row["customer_email"]."',"."'".$row["shipping_description"]; 
        echo $str;}
```

function dbDisconnect()----mysql disconnect

function oradbConnect()

```
function oradbInsert()
     {

            $qry1= "INSERT INTO Test(po_number , Po_creation_date , customer_firstname , customer_lastname , customer_email , shipping_description) values(".$str");
            $p= oci_parse($conn,$qry1);
            oci_execute($p);
     }
```

So how should I pass $str from Mysql to Oracle so that data from Mysql will insert into Oracle...

Comment: please would you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the fetch function to return the values. Note: I made `$str` an array, as you were fetching values in a loop. If you only selecting a single row, change this.

```
function dbFetch(){
  $a = mysql_insert_id();    
  $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample where order_primary = $a");
  $str = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $str[] = "'".$row["po_number"]."',"."'".$row[created_at]."',"."'".$row["ustomer_firstname"]."',"."'".$row["customer_lastname"]."',"."'".$row["customer_email"]."',"."'".$row["shipping_description"]."'";      
  } 
  return $str;
}
```

Then pass the return value to the insert function. Again the note: I used an array here, if that is not needed, the code could be simpler.

```
function oradbInsert($str){      
  $qry1= "INSERT INTO Test(po_number , Po_creation_date , customer_firstname , customer_lastname , customer_email , shipping_description) values(:val)";
  $p= oci_parse($conn,$qry1);
  oci_bind_by_name($p, ':val', $v);
  foreach ($str as $v) {
    oci_execute($p);
  }
 }
```

Final note: This is not tested.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, when you have two functions that need to share data it is one of the reasons objects exist in the first place.

```
class ImportantData {
  protected $some_data;
  public function retrieveData() {
    $this->some_data = 'retrieved from db';
  }
  public function useData() {
    // use $this->some_data for something
  }
}

$importantData = new ImportantData();

$importantData->retrieveData();
$importantData->useData();
```

Of course this might or might not be feasible in your specific case, but it is a popular solution.